# how to edit a permutation

Tags: python, permutation, python-itertools

every number is a port.
and the permutation gives me all possible routes but my starting port is always number 1,so out of all combinations i want the ones that start with 1.

this is all i got so far

```
from itertools import permutations

routes = permutations([1 , 2, 3 ,4 , 5])
for i in list(routes):
      print(i)
```

is there a way to enable me to pick those specific combinations?

Comment: You could take the 24 permutations of (2, 3, 4, 5), (you already know how to do that) and then prepend a 1 onto them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply add a 1 to the beginning of the permutations of 2,3,4,5. For example,

```
from itertools import permutations

routes = permutations([2, 3 ,4 , 5])
for i in routes:
      print([1,*i])
```

If you really want to generate every permutation and filter down to those starting with 1, you could do the following.

```
from itertools import permutations

routes = permutations([1,2, 3 ,4 , 5])
for i in routes:
    if i[0] == 1:
        print(i)
```